# select the parent li in a list without selecing its children in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, selector

I have following piece of code.

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav">
         <li class="main1"><a href="about.php">about us</a>
              <ul class="sub_menu">
                   <li><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="2.html">2</a></li>
              </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need that sub_menu gets visible when mouse stands over class "main1" and not its chilren.

So I used the following code

```
$(".main1").mouseover(function(){
     $(".main1.sub_menu").css("opacity","1");
});
```

That works fine, but the problem is that even when I place the mouse over sub_menu and its children (while their opacity is zero) the sub_menu  gets appear. While I just need the sub_menu gets visible when I directly place the mouse over "about us" link.

I searched alot but none of the solutions seemed suitable for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

`$(".main1").mouseover(function(){
     $(".main1.sub_menu").css("opacity","1");
});`

to

`$(".main1 a").mouseover(function(){
     $(".main1.sub_menu").css("opacity","1");
});`

and incase you have more anchor tags besides about us, giving it an id like `id="aboutus"`
and use it in jquery like this:

`$("#aboutus").mouseover(function(){
     $(".main1.sub_menu").css("opacity","1");
});`

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$(".main1.sub_menu").css("opacity","1");
```

to this:

```
$(this).find(".sub_menu").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/pESq6/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav">
         <li class="main1"><a href="about.php">about us</a>
              <ul class="sub_menu" style="opacity:0">
                   <li><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="2.html">2</a></li>
              </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".main1").hover(function(){
     $(".main1 .sub_menu").css("opacity","1");
},function(){
     $(".main1 .sub_menu").css("opacity","0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having this issue because you are applying mouseover event to main1 which also contains sub elements. change it to:

```
$(".about_us").mouseover(function(){
     $(".main1.sub_menu").css("opacity","1");
});
```

and add a class about_us to your about us link.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
  $(".main1 :contains(about us)").hover(function () {
        alert(1);
    });
```